# ImageMagick images are all blank and some gray when too big image was made to 256x256 tiles

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

When I convert 40000x40000px size of image to tiles sized 256x256px, all the images sized 256x256px are blank or gray. But when I make tiles from 20000x40000px image, then everything is OK. Also if I halve the 40000x40000px to 20000x40000px with ImageMagick, then it works well too.

My guesses are that maybe I have not enough space on disk or I don't have enough RAM. I was make tiles on 35gb disk and with 8gb of ram.

Also maybe my config is not good?

My Config:

```
<policymap>
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="8GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="60GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="width" value="500KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="height" value="500KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="area" value="250000KP"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="60GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="4"/>
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="URL" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTPS" />
  <policy domain="delegate" rights="none" pattern="HTTP" />
  <policy domain="path" rights="none" pattern="@*"/>
  <policy domain="cache" name="shared-secret" value="passphrase" stealth="true"/>
</policymap>
```

Comment: Probably not enough RAM. Not enough space to make the last resolution level. Or perhaps out of space in /tmp directory.

Comment: @fmw42 Is it possible to tell the program somehow to complete the task with my 8gb of ram? I tested that if I run out of space, it tells me it immediately. I still have 15gb of left when doing the task. I have x86_64 version of ImageMagick.

Comment: Check your /tmp directory or wherever you have set up to have ImageMagick put its temporary files. If it fills up that space in that directory on disk, it will fail.

Comment: I do not understand your comment about having 16GB left after running when you only have 8GB RAM.

Comment: You have 40,000 x 40,000 pixels. So that is 1.6 GB for a single channel. If your image is color it has 3 channels so 4.8 GB for the input and 4.8 GB for the output. That is 9.6 GB. So you are running out of RAM.

Comment: @fmw42 I meant 15gb of SSD memory.

So it's impossible to make tiles straight from 40,000 x 40,000 pixels with 8 GB of RAM? Cant just ImageMagick just do it's job slower or something, to complete it with 8 GB of RAM?

Comment: Sorry, no.  the SSD memory is ok. It is the RAM. ImageMagick needs more than you have. It is not an issue of speed, but storage for the data while being converted. You can change your policy to use more disk in place of RAM. That will be slower but should finish. Increase the disk and map policies in the policy.xml file. See https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php and https://imagemagick.org/script/architecture.php#tera-pixel

Comment: @fmw42 Well.. I made space to my SSD and still I have white blank images after making tiles while I have 30 GB of free space on my SSD while rendering.

Comment: @fmw42 I also noticed now that if I put 40,000x40,000px image, I can see on Task Manager that convert-im6.q16 work is suspended. That should be the case why I have blank images. It also uses only 1GB of ram and 15GB of my SSD when trying to convert such big image.

Comment: @fmw42 It also makes 256x10 and 256x20 sized tiles instead of 256x256 when 40,000x40,000px image.

Comment: Why is work suspended? Does that happen on successful conversions? If not, then find out why it happens for the other case. Some limit is being exceeded and ImageMagick stops.

Comment: What is the input image format?

Comment: @fmw42 Oh well I tested it now many times. It does not get suspended all the time (successful images with less pixels don't get suspended). But maybe my <policymap> settings are not good enough? Could you look it over, maybe something is missing for big images like that? Also my TMP files never go above 14.1013 GB. My Image format is PNG. Also I am using ImageMagick version 6.9.10.

Comment: Are there left over imagemagick files in the /tmp directory that do not delete automatically.  How much free SSD disk space do you have? If too close to 15 GB, then it is possible that you are actually running out of SSD space.

Comment: PNG does not support tiled output format to my knowledge. What is the output format?

Comment: @fmw42 Imagemagick files in /tmp are deleted automatically. I have 35GB of free SSD disk space after it used only 14.1013 GB of it. PNG to PNG has been working with 20,000x40,000px image. Maybe I need to make clean up my PNG files with some kind of compressor before tiling? Well I am going to try something smaller than PNG if it does not help. I am using this program to make tiles for map like Google Maps, but my own map. https://github.com/jahed/maptiles . Also if I just did normal tiles with 40,000x40,000px without zooming, it still is doing white empty images.

Comment: Also It's 48 Bit image. Maybe this could be the problem?

Comment: @fmw42 I converted PNG to JPG (best quality possible) with GIMP. Now converting works well, but how should I keep the best quality possible? Should I convert back JPG to PNG? I would like to keep the best quality as possible (thinking about creating map and zooming into it). PNG file is 687,624 KB and JPG file is 581,942 KB.

Comment: Interestingly it started using more SSD space and RAM when converting JPG.

Comment: Once you use JPG you have lost quality, so it cannot be recovered by converting to PNG from JPG.  The issue appears to be one of RAM or disk space due to the use of 48-bit images? Is that 3 16-bit channels? JPG works because it does not support 16-bit channels. It is likely only 8-bit channels so 24-bits. Do you understand that. As a test, try `convert image.png -depth 8 ....` and see if that works. It will likely due to the conversion to depth 8.

Comment: Try `magick -monitor -limit memory 2GiB -limit map 4GiB image.png ...` This will be slower.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried Depth and limiting memory and map. Nothing worked. I think I need to decrease PNG a little or find something else instead of JPG.

Comment: What do you get from `convert -list resource`

Comment: @fmw42 Sorry for answering late. I discovered that my image was bugged somehow for ImageMagick. I made a fake cutting to the image. (cut 0px from a random side) and then it worked flawlessly. The bug came back when I cut the image to 2 pieces with this: `-crop 50%x100% +repage` but when I cut it to 4 pieces with this: `-crop 2x2@ +repage` then it worked.